# Bundle Activity contents to transfer to next Activity in android

Tags: android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
          {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_user_details);         
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);         
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
               {
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                 Intent nxtpage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChangePassword.class);

                edtName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
                edtPhoneNumber= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_phone_number);

                String Name=(String)edtName.getText().toString();
                String PhoneNumber=(String)edtPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

              //Create the bundle
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                //Add your data to bundle
                bundle.putString(“Name”,Name);
                bundle.putString(“PhoneNumber”,PhoneNumber);

                //Add the bundle to the intent
                nxtpage.putExtras(bundle);

              //Fire that second activity
                 startActivity(nxtpage);
             }

  }
}
}
```

I m trying to bundle this activity[register_user] values like name and phonenumber and send to other activity[regist] but here its showing error in

```
                bundle.putString(“Name”,Name);
                bundle.putString(“PhoneNumber”,PhoneNumber);
```

> error:Syntax error on tokens, ArgumentList expected instead

can anyone pls tell what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
  bundle.putString(“Name”,Name);
```

to

```
  bundle.putString("Name",Name);
```

Similarly

```
  bundle.putString("PhoneNumber",PhoneNumber);
```

You need to  `""` instead of `“”`

Comment: hi @raghunandan if i have to pass imageview image along with dis how is tat possible could u pls tel me

Comment: @andy image is stored some where in memory. Now get the path of the image and then use the same method.

Comment: hi @Raghunandan i have extracted values String Name = bundle.getString("Name"); in oncreate method but how to use the value of Name in class beneth the oncreate method...

Comment: @andy declare the variable `String Name` before `onCreate` asinstance variable and use `Name = bundle.getString("Name");`

Answer (score 0):

here is name conflict is happen between string Name  and string PhoneNumber

please try

```
bundle.putString("name",Name);

bundle.putString("phonenumber",PhoneNumber);
```

Comment: if i have to pass ImageView image how can send

Comment: there is no conflict of name here. `"Name"`and `Name` are not the same. One is the key other is the value. The value is a valid string and can be anythign